# PHP MySql query error when executing SP

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have a PHP script which fires a MySQL SP. The SP cmd works when run directly against db (I'm using PhpMyAdmin UI). When tested, the PHP returns error 'Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource' due to the fact there is nothing returned from the SP...when i debug the script i see the variable $result1 has all its params set to null.

There is another SP executed successfully using the same code above this one in the script so im a bit puzzled. Any ideas what the issue is?

```
$result1 = $mysqli->query("CALL sp_playerInvite_pin_select('samsmith@hotmail.com')");
if(!$result1) die("CALL failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error);
//echo json_encode($getPlayerInvitePin);

// check for empty result, if not then there is >1 pin corresponding to email
if (mysql_num_rows($result1) > 0) 
{
    //looping through all results-in theory should only 1 result
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) 
    {
        $response["pin"] = $row["player_pin"];
    }
// echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

The SP...[image]

Comment: You should show the code of your `sp`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `mysqli_num_rows`? Also your `if` is not properly closed.

Comment: The error you showed up its usually happen when the query (SQL) is not alright.

Comment: SP added. SP run against the DB works.

Comment: Its not the SP AFAIKS

Comment: it was the missing 'i' - thanks 'I Can Has Cheezburger' :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be mysqli_num_rows?  thanks 'I Can Has Cheezburger' :